# HTML, JS, and CSS How can I hide text when it's Opacity = 0 and unhide it when Opacity > 0?

Tags: html, css

I am currently designing a webpage and I have two content elements on it that I would like to hide when their opacity is set to 0. The elements are getting in the way when the user tries to click on other buttons. To accomplish this, I am planning to use HTML and CSS code to manipulate the visibility of the content elements. However, I am not sure about the best way to implement this. Can you provide some guidance on how to effectively hide the elements when their opacity is set to 0 using HTML and CSS?
HTML:

```html
<content class="description">...</content>
<content class="description2">...</content>
```

CSS:

```css
.description {
    font-family: Inter;
    z-index: 1;
    font-weight: 200;
    position: fixed;
    color: rgb(255 255 255);
    font-size: 2rem;
    left: 15%;
    bottom: 33%;
    transform: translate(-15%, -33%);
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
    cursor: default;
}

.description2 {
    font-family: Inter;
    z-index: 1;
    font-weight: 200;
    position: fixed;
    color: rgb(255 255 255);
    font-size: 2rem;
    left: 15%;
    bottom: 33%;
    transform: translate(-15%, -33%);
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than `opacity: 0`, you can consider using [`pointer-events` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). When it is set to `none`, it allows the element to act as if it cannot handle any events / interactions. (This works well even if you have transition / animation on the `opacity` attribute)

An alternative option would be [`visibility` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility), which also will not affect the layout. However, it doesn't work well with transition / animation